# Why won't VS 2010 virtual server recognize a path starting with "/"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I design my web-application, I like to use "/" to designate the access to the root directory.  Now, this works perfectly on my production site run on IIS 7.5.

However, when I try to run the site on VS 2010's virtual server, I keep getting 404 errors for any path that starts with "/".

Now, when I get a 404 error, the address in the addressbar is the correct address.  For example, I have a link to `/index.aspx' - and on the iis7.5 webserver, the path becomes`http://my.site.com/index.aspx`and it navigates perfectly.  However on the VS virtual server, the path becomes`http://localhost:61679/index.aspx` and I get a 404 error.

However, if I don't use the "/" in the path - that is, I either use a full path or leave it off, then the virtual server navigates to `http://localhost:61679/index.aspx` like is supposed to.

So the address is the same whether the "/" is the first character or not.

None of these links are using `runat="server"`, so I don't need to worry about using `~`.

Is there a setting somewhere to enable this?

**[update]**

I have a few more clues:
  - When I navigate to `http://localhost:61679/index.aspx` it gets a 404.
  - If I navigate to `http://localhost:61679/mysite/index.aspx` it loads fine.
  - Links that start with "/" lead to `http://localhost:61679/` NOT `http://localhost:61679/mysite`.
  - This means that the "/" tells the VS server to navigate to the root of the server, not to the root of the site.  However, it doesn't work this way in IIS.

If I tell VS to use IIS Express, everything works just fine.

That means there must be a setting somewhere to make "/" refer to the root of the site for Visual Studio's built-in server (I have referred to it as "virtual server").

Comment: When you get the 404 error, if you go into the address bar and press enter (e.g. reload that address) you still get a 404? If you *manually* enter the address - do you get a 404?

Comment: Yes to both questions.  Also, no images nor scripts that are called from the masterpage show or run if they use the path that way.

Comment: However, if I just navigate to `http://localhost:61679/`, even though the server is still running, I get a 404 on that, too.  I have the settings to use the default browser, which is Firefox.

Comment: Ah!  But if I navigate to `http://localhost:61679/mysite/index.aspx` then it works.  So it looks like the `/` in the virtual server refers to the server's root, not the site's root.  But it doesn't work like that in IIS.

Comment: When you say *Virtual Server* are you referring to the *Asp.Net Development Server*?

Comment: @Blachshma - I'm sorry, yes, that's what I mean.